# Uncaught ReferenceError: getDropdownData is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getDropdownData('<?php echo $userLoggedIn;?>', 'message')"><i class="fas fa-inbox"></i></a>
```

i'm linking my script file before the function calling.

as so.

`<script src="assets/js/fanzentral.js"></script>`

which contains the js function as below.

i get the in the console that the it is an uncaught reference error. no thing happens when I click on  the inbox button.

```
function getDropdownData(user, type){
    if($(".dropdown_data_window").css("height") == "0px"){
        var pageName;

        if(type == 'notification'){

        }
        else if(type == 'message'){
            pageName="ajax_load_messages.php";
            $("span").remove("#unread_message");
        }

        var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
            url "includes/handlers/" + pageName,
            type"POST",
            data:"page=1&userLoggedIn="+user,
            cache:false,

            success:function(response){
                $(".dropdown_data_window").html(response);
                $(".dropdown_data_window").css({"padding":"0px", "height": "280px"});
                $("#dropdown_data_type").val(type);

            }
        });
    }

    else{
        $(".dropdown_data_window").html("");
        $(".dropdown_data_window").css({"padding":"0px", "height": "0px"});

    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect [this answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514383/attribute-onclick-function-not-functioning-as-intended). Is `getDropdownData` a global? Or is it inside something like a DOMContentLoaded or jQuery `ready` or similar callback?

Comment: it is a global function.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). With the above, you shouldn't get that error, because `getDropdownData` is definitely defined.

Comment: Solved it! Thanks @T.J.Crowder. turns out I just missed some : in my definition of `getDropdownData`

Comment: That's great! Happy coding!