# Javascript insertAdjacentHTML a tag with an onclick event

Tags: javascript, onclick, inserthtml

When a checkbox is checked I insert a new a tag to display what is selected. I add an onclick event to that a tag but when I cick on it for some reason it gives me an error that the function cannot be found.

```js
const removeItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.remove();
}
document.querySelectorAll('.choose').forEach(choose => {
  choose.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      document.getElementById('selected').insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        `<a id="chosen-${e.target.id}" href="" onclick="removeItem()">${e.target.value}<i class="icon-close"></i></a>`
      );
    }  else {
      console.log('remove')

    }
      // document.getElementById('selected').querySelect('selectedItem').remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<label>
 <input
  value="Value 1"
  id="1"
  class="choose"
  type="checkbox"
  data-np-invisible="1"
  data-np-checked="0"
 /> 
Add Value 1
</label>
<div id="selected"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attribute onclick="function()" not functioning as intended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514383/attribute-onclick-function-not-functioning-as-intended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it in the snippet and it looks like `e` is undefined. You need to pass `event` to the `removeItem` function here:

```js
`<a id="chosen-${e.target.id}" href="" onclick="removeItem(event)">${e.target.value}<i class="icon-close"></i></a>`
```

Comment: This is definitely an issue, but not the "_function cannot be found_" error OP is asking about.

Comment: It turned out it was. No idea why it was giving me such error.

Comment: If you read the error message carefully you will see that it says **Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined**. It does not say that **your function** could not be found. Your function was definitely found and did execute but failed for the reason described above.